# Dropwizard and intelliJ autocompletes not working? (Using maven)

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, dropwizard

I have the following dependencies in my pom :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-auth</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I have built the project, to make sure everything needed is in place - but then when I write the following code :

```
public class BasicAuthentication implements Authenticator {
    // I am aware that Authenticator takes arguments, but this is a separate issue. :)
}
```

For some reason, as I type out the word "Authenticator" - the auto complete suggestions for that class are for java, sun, etc - the dropwizard.auth one is not there.

Any idea what is going on?

I am tagging Maven, intelliJ, and Dropwizard in the question, because I am unaway which of these is actually causing the issue...

EDIT : nobody really seems to have an answer for this - should I just abandon and go to something that has traditionally worked for me, like Spring?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure 'Enable auto import' is on for Maven projects and the library is visible under external libraries in the project view.

> Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing |
>   Import Maven projects automatically.

You can also right click in project view.

> Right click | Maven | Reimport.

If the issue still persists, you can try

> File | Invalidate caches / Restart option in IntelliJ.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks, but it appears as though none of these fix my problem.

Comment: @MickeyThreeSheds Is bom dependency under dependencyManagement tag?
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
                <artifactId>dropwizard-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

Please try removing scope import for the dropwizard-auth and verify that dropwizard.version is specified under the properties.

Comment: @MickeyThreeSheds do refer this [StackOverflow | maven-bom-bill-of-materials-dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496022/maven-bom-bill-of-materials-dependency)