# Sharing code between node.js based micro-services?

Tags: javascript, node.js, maven

Assume I have a microservice A and a microservice (implemented on node.js)  B which both depends on package C.

When I release my application (which includes A,B and C) I want to make sure that the same version of C is used by both A and B. I want this to be the case whenever I release A or B during development.

In fact with Java and Maven there is the concept of a BOM (bill of materials) see for example, which solves this for Java.

[Maven BOM [Bill Of Materials] Dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496022/maven-bom-bill-of-materials-dependency)

Is there a similar solution for node.js?

Comment: What are you using as a dependency manager? [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/) generates [yarn.lock](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/yarn-lock/) file to fix the package version. So all you need is a yarn.lock at the root to ensure that the module version remains same

Comment: ATM its npm but I'm still open to switch to yarn. Yes I like the yarn.lock fil approach, but I'm not sure how it would work because my microservices are in separate repositories.

Comment: You would need to have same `yarn.lock` in the two repositories. This will ensure the same versions across the repo.  Here is the [doc](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/migrating-from-npm/)